# Swift 3: NSURL to URL missing init?

Tags: swift, url, nsurl

I just used XCode 8 and let it convert my existing project. Now I face the error that there is no init function for new URL without parameters.

```
class fileObj : NSObject, NSCopying, Comparable {
    var URL                   = NSURL()    // initial
...
```

The new code looks like:

```
class fileObj : NSObject, NSCopying, Comparable {
    var myUrl                 = Foundation.URL()    // initial
...
```

How should I init the new URL var?

Comment: what is the purpose of having an immutable object without any value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observation is indeed correct, there is no empty initialiser because this would be an invalid URL, therefore they decided to disallow that.

What I recommend you doing is not initialising the variable at first and making it an optional (`URL?`). Later in the code, you'll be able to initialise it.

Comment: Ok, good to know that I'm not blind. :-) My quick & dirty solution is to use URL(fileURLWithPath: ""). Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

it makes **absolutely zero sense** to do so, but currently *(Swift3, Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a))* it is working and gives you a totally blank `URL` object with no purpose at all, as you just asked for.

```
var myURL: URL = NSURLComponents().url!
```

Comment: When the app is running again, I can check the reason, why the init was used and improve it that way. But first task is to make it run like it was before.